# Serve image through ajax in html helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I am curios about a thing. Let's say I am saving images in a SQL Database ( I know it's not recommended; the best way it's to save only a reference to a image saved somewhere else, but I want to ask you something about this specific case ).

I am serving a file like this :

```
 public ActionResult Serve(int id)
    {
        ......
        return File(img.Content, img.ContentType);
    }
```

I have also made an `Html helper` :

```
   public static HtmlString ServeImage(this HtmlHelper html, int id)
    {
        var urlHelper= new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);

        var tag= "<img  src='{0}' width='200' height='200' />";

        return new HtmlString(string.Format(imageTag, urlHelper.Action("Serve", "Image", new { id = id })));
    }
```

So, when I want to show a picture I am writing in a view something like this: `@Html.ServeImage(imageId)`

My question is: **Is there any way yo call `urlHelper.Action("Serve", "Image", new { id = id })))` through ajax and still use my helper? **

I have read about Ajax Helpers but I think it doesn't help me here and I have only one option left. I need to give up my helper and call my action with ajax like I normally do. Is this right?

I mean:

`$.ajax(function() {
.....
});`

Comment: Why do you need an AJAX call? What exactly are you trying to achieve? You could make an AJAX call to a controller action that returns a partial view containing a call to your custom helper `@Html.ServeImage(imageId)`.

Comment: I was curios if there's a method to call an html helper with ajax. Just for learning new things. Anyway, what you are saying makes sense :). I can do that too.

Comment: No, there's no way to call an HTML helper with AJAX. This doesn't make sense. AJAX is used to call server side endpoints (a.k.a controller actions in ASP.NET MVC).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a plain img tag and set the src to @urlHelper.Action("Serve", "Image", new { id = id })))

Example:

```
<img src='@urlHelper.Action("Serve", "Image", new { id = id })' width='200' height='200' />
```

Comment: What this have to do with my question ?